# How to make Dynamic textbox transparent in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, textbox, transparent, dynamic-text

so I have a dynamic textbox, with the var as text_Box. For some reason the Dynamic text box has a white background, that I can't remove. Is there a way I can change the color, or make it transparent, so that way the text is only showing? Remeber this is in AS3. Thanks in advanced. [Trying to remove the white background, so only text is showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5aBA.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming text_Box is a TextField object - try adding the following to your code:

```
text_Box.background = false;
```

Comment: For some reason it does not work, and gives an error saying that it doesn't recognize the variable name. I defined it, and gave the textbox that variable name.

Comment: Never mind, it works! Thank you! Is there a way to do it with the border?

Comment: Hetesh, Glad to hear you got it working! With regards to your most recent question, do you mean to ask if there's a way to make the TextField object's border invisible? if so, text_Box.border = false; should do the trick. And in further exploits of your usage of the TextField object, I would recommend checking out the AS3 API on the TextField object. You can find that here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html Best of luck!